# Obtener totales de campos Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

estoy desarrollando un formulario con lineas de detalle.. El problema es que no consigo obtener los totales de las columnas.. (sumatorias totales)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se muestra en la imagen deseo obtener la sumatoria de "prec_oz" y mandarlo en el input "peso Ozs", que seria : 3,295.5 del mismo modo para la columna "total" , que igualmente seria "11254.841 + 544.59 = 11,799.431 ... El problema que no logro realizarlo T.T........

codigo HTML `

```
                                        <table id="laboratorios"
                                            class="table table-striped table-bordered order-list-trabajovarios">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Orden</th>
                                                    <th>Lote</th>
                                                    <th>Grs</th>
                                                    <th>Fineza</th>
                                                    <th>Grs_Pagables</th>
                                                    <th>Prec_Oz</th>
                                                    <th>Total</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input name="detalleVario[0].orden" id="travar-0-trabajo" class="input-group has-success">
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input name="detalleVario[0].lote" id="travar-0-lote" class="input-group has-success">
                                                    </td>
                                            <td>
                                                        <input name="detalleVario[0].grs" id="travar-0-grs" class="input-group has-success" onfocusout="focusoutTraVarCantidad(0)">
                                                    </td>
                                                    
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input name="detalleVario[0].precio" id="travar-0-precio" class="input-group has-success" value="99.97" readonly="readonly" 
                                                        style='background-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.3); border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid rgba(118, 118, 118, 0.2); cursor: default;'>
                                                    </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input name="detalleVario[0].total" id="travar-0-total" class="input-group has-success" readonly="readonly" 
                                                        style='background-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.3); border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid rgba(118, 118, 118, 0.2); cursor: default;'>
                                                
                                                    </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <input name="detalleVario[0].prec_Oz" id="travar-0-prec_Oz" class="input-group has-success" onfocusout="focusoutTraVarCantidad2(0)">
                                                    </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <input name="detalleVario[0].total2" id="travar-0-total2" class="input-group has-success" readonly="readonly" 
                                                        style='background-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.3); border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid rgba(118, 118, 118, 0.2); cursor: default;'>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <button class="ibtnDel btn btn-danger">
                                                            <i class="material-icons">close</i> Quitar
                                                        </button>
                                                    </td>

                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"
                                            onClick="addTrabajosVarios();">
                                            <span class="btn-label"> <i class="material-icons">check</i>
                                            </span> Agregar
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>`
```

y en el java script utilizo las siguientes funciones para que me calculen ciertas columnas :

```
function addTrabajosVarios() {
            var newRow = $("<tr>");
            var cols = "";
            cols += '<td><input name="detalleVario['+countTraVar+'].orden" type="text" id="travar-' + countTraVar + '-orden"  class="input-group has-success" /></td>';
            cols += '<td><input name="detalleVario['+countTraVar+'].lote" type="text" id="travar-' + countTraVar + '-lote"    class="input-group has-success" /></td>';

            cols += '<td><input name="detalleVario['+countTraVar+'].grs" type="text" id="travar-' + countTraVar + '-grs"  class="input-group has-success" onfocusout="focusoutTraVarCantidad(' + countTraVar + ')"   /></td>';
            cols += '<td><input name="detalleVario['+countTraVar+'].precio" type="text" id="travar-' + countTraVar + '-precio"  class="input-group has-success" value="99.97" readonly="readonly" style="background-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.3); border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid rgba(118, 118, 118, 0.2); cursor: default;" /></td>';
            cols += '<td><input name="detalleVario['+countTraVar+'].total" type="text" id="travar-' + countTraVar + '-total"   class="input-group has-success"  readonly="readonly" style="background-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.3); border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid rgba(118, 118, 118, 0.2); cursor: default;" /></td>';
            cols += '<td><input name="detalleVario['+countTraVar+'].prec_Oz" type="text" id="travar-' + countTraVar + '-prec_Oz"  class="input-group has-success" onfocusout="focusoutTraVarCantidad2(' + countTraVar + ')"   /></td>';
            cols += '<td><input name="detalleVario['+countTraVar+'].total2" type="text" id="travar-' + countTraVar + '-total2"  class="input-group has-success"  readonly="readonly" style="background-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.3); border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid rgba(118, 118, 118, 0.2); cursor: default;" /></td>';
           
         
            cols += '<td style="display: none;"><input name="detalleVario['+countTraVar+'].tipo" id="travar-'+countTraVar+'-tipo" type="hidden" value="TVA" readonly="readonly"></td>';
            
            cols += '<td><button class="ibtnDel btn btn-danger"> <i class="material-icons">close</i> Quitar </button></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("table.order-list-trabajovarios").append(newRow);
            countTraVar++;
            countDeleteTraVar++;
        }

        $("table.order-list-trabajovarios").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(event) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            countDeleteTraVar -= 1
        });
         let floatTotal=0;
        function focusoutTraVarCantidad(numero) {
            var idCantidad = "#travar-" + numero + "-grs";
         var valueCantidad = parseFloat($(idCantidad).val());
        
            if (!isNaN(valueCantidad)) {
                var idTotal = "#travar-" + numero + "-total";
                floatTotal = (valueCantidad * (99.97/100));
                var fltotal = (valueCantidad * (99.97/100)).toLocaleString();
                    
                    
             $(idTotal).val(fltotal);
                
              
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        }
    function focusoutTraVarCantidad2(numero) {
            var idPrec_Oz = "#travar-" + numero + "-prec_Oz";
         var valuetotal2 = parseFloat($(idPrec_Oz).val());
    
            if (!isNaN(valuetotal2)) {
                var idTotals2 = "#travar-" + numero + "-total2";
                var floatTotal2 = (valuetotal2 * (floatTotal / (31.1035) )).toLocaleString();
              
                
                $(idTotals2).val(floatTotal2);
                
        
                
       }
        }
```

De ante mano agradezco el apoyo. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crearía una **función para calcular los totales**, esa función sería llamado en varios eventos.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // cuando carga la pagina se calcula los totales
    calculoTotales();

    $("table.order-list-trabajovarios").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        //countDeleteTraVar -= 1

        // al final
        calculoTotales();
    });
});
function calculoTotales() {
    // acumuladores
    let prec_Oz = 0;
    let total2 = 0;

    //obtenemos las filas
    let filas = $('table.order-list-trabajovarios tbody').find('tr')

    // recorremos las filas
    filas.each(function(indice, fila) {

        // eq(indice de la columna empezando por 0)
        let input_prec_Oz = $(this).find('td:eq(5)').find('input'); // input
        let input_total2 = $(this).find('td:eq(6)').find('input'); // input

        let value_input_prec_Oz = 0;
        let value_input_total2 = 0;

        // podria haber más validaciones aparte del vacio
        if (input_prec_Oz.val().trim() !== '') {
            value_input_prec_Oz = parseFloat(input_prec_Oz.val());
        }

        // podria haber más validaciones aparte del vacio
        if (input_total2.val().trim() !== '') {
            value_input_total2 = parseFloat(input_total2.val());
        }

        prec_Oz += value_input_prec_Oz;
        total2 += value_input_total2;
    });

    // representamos los totales en el input correspondiente
    // toFixed es opcional
    $('#total_peso_ozs').val(prec_Oz.toFixed(2));
    $('#total_us').val(total2.toFixed(2));
}

function focusoutTraVarCantidad2(numero) {


    // al final
    calculoTotales();
}

function addTrabajosVarios() {


    // al final
    calculoTotales();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Datos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="order-list-trabajovarios" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Orden</th>
                <th>Lote</th>
                <th>Grs</th>
                <th>Fineza</th>
                <th>Grs_Pagables</th>
                <th>Prec_Oz</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>col0</td>
                <td>col1</td>
                <td>col2</td>
                <td>col3</td>
                <td>col4</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="travar-0-prec_Oz" value="5" onfocusout="focusoutTraVarCantidad2(0)"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="travar-0-total2" value="10" readonly></td>
                <td>
                    <button class="ibtnDel">Quitar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>col0</td>
                <td>col1</td>
                <td>col2</td>
                <td>col3</td>
                <td>col4</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="travar-1-prec_Oz" value="6" onfocusout="focusoutTraVarCantidad2(1)"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="travar-1-total2" value="12" readonly></td>
                <td>
                    <button class="ibtnDel">Quitar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>col0</td>
                <td>col1</td>
                <td>col2</td>
                <td>col3</td>
                <td>col4</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="travar-2-prec_Oz" value="8" onfocusout="focusoutTraVarCantidad2(2)"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="travar-2-total2" value="16" readonly></td>
                <td>
                    <button class="ibtnDel">Quitar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <hr>
    <h2>Totales</h2>
    <div>
        <label for="total_peso_ozs">Peso Ozs</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="total_peso_ozs" value="0.00">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="total_us">Total US$</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="total_us" value="0.00">
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que colocar a cada columna una misma clase y luego haces lo siguiente.

```
$('.clase').blur(function () {
    let sum = 0;
    $('.clase').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });

    $('#idTotalDeEsaColumna').val(sum);
});​​​​​​​​​
```

El metodo blur de jquery se dispara cada vez que cambias de input, es decir, cuando este pierde el foco.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.uno').blur(function () {
      let sum = 0;
      $('.uno').each(function() {
          sum += Number($(this).val());
      });
      $('#total-uno').val(sum);
  });
  
  $('.dos').blur(function () {
      let sum = 0;
      $('.dos').each(function() {
          sum += Number($(this).val());
      });
      $('#total-dos').val(sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="uno">
<input type="text" class="uno">
<input type="text" id="total-uno" placeholder="total-uno">
<br>
<input type="text" class="dos">
<input type="text" class="dos">
<input type="text" id="total-dos" placeholder="total-dos">
```